# Problems in creating CRNA

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

Im just stared learning react Native, and while creating a CRNA I had this :

```
`C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\Projet> expo init MoviesAndMe

? Choose a template: expo-template-blank

? Choose which workflow to use: managed

√ Please enter a few initial configuration values.

Read more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration · 100% completed

[17:21:41] Extracting project files...

[17:21:45] Customizing project...

[17:21:45] Installing dependencies...

npm ERR! path git

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall spawn git

npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:

npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/expo/react-native-maps.git

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mohamed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-17T16_22_16_022Z-debug.log

[17:22:16] Process exited with non-zero code: 1

[17:22:16] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.`
```

Comment: Have you looked at the content of the log that was created? What errors were contained in it? Do you have `git` installed on your system?

Comment: `ENOENT` is a POSIX error code meaning "NO ENTity found". This barf from `npm` looks quite unusable but it suggests `npm` was not able to find the `git` executable in the `%PATH%`. So dig from there.